# How to handle a variable number of algorithms in a kernel?

Tags: opencl

I'm capturing video frames. Every frame is passed into the kernel as an Image2D. I've got about five simple image processing algorithms (blur, sharpen etc.) which a user can choose of (also a combination of different ones is possible). I see three possibilities here:

1. One kernel: At runtime construct the string of the kernel with the
   chosen algorithms and compile (and take the overhead of the one-time
   compiling delay)
2. One kernel: Handle the chosen algorithms with flags (although I understand that conditional branches are undesirable)
3. Many kernels (one per algorithm): Seems to be the issue, that an `Image2D` can either be `read_only` or `write_only` and I would need to repetively copy the image from and to the GPU as one output image of a kernel is the input image of the next kernel.

Is there a suggested rule of thumb which way to follow?

Comment: Regarding conditional execution: the kind of branching you are talking about is probably not that bad.  Every work item is still going down the same path for a given kernel execution.  It's the situations where different work items are branching in different directions that will really kill your performance.

Comment: Thanks James, I will evaluate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One workaround for the readonly/writeonly problem could be to use buffers for the middle steps.

Image2D -> buffer0 -> buffer1 -> ... bufferN -> Image2D

Or use two buffers and alternate with them if you don't need the intermediate results. (I2d, B0, B1, B0, ..., I2D)

You would probably need to know in advance how many filters you are applying, but that shouldn't be much of an issue.

Comment: Interesting thought. Well, in this case one buffer would be sufficient, as the algorithms are applied in sequence.

Comment: I was wrong about the single buffer, of course. You need at least two buffer internally.

Comment: I went with this approach and found it more elegant. In one kernel there's still the mentioned branching, however, the branch is leading to the same path for all work items. I timed it and it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you try and avoid the first two options

1. This way you will have a very unreadable and complicated kernel code. which is OK if you are a 100% sure that the code does what it is supposed to do. That is with considerations on the arrangement and grouping of your work-items. The point is that it will be difficult and to debug and maintain your kernels this way.
2. This, I think, is even worse than the first option if your threads can go down in different paths. Simple branching can reduce your performances and create troubles for synchronizations. IN ADDITION to simple branching you should consider the fact that your algorithms might require different number and arrangement of threads. If that is the case then using one kernel for all operations is a really bad idea.

I haven't tried it myself but I think you should try out the option suggested by @mfa.

Comment: Have a look at James' comment: He's assuming that the second way might not be that bad, as all work items still go down the same path. The kernel is differing only between frames, where a new kernel is enqueued for execution before every frame. I will report, what my tries eventually led to.